# CakePHP Issue - Query second table

Tags: cakephp

I am unsure how to do this. I need to query a secondary table to pull the name of a category based on a id of another table. All dynamically.

I tried `hasmany`, `hasone`, I could not get anything to work.
here what I got

I have 2 Tables:

```
Advertisments id | adname | adsite_id    
adsite_id == adsites.id

adsites
id | name
```

I am trying to display the table of advertisements and replacing the adsite_id with the name of the adsite.name.

I cannot figure this out.

AdvertismentController:

`function index() {
        $this->set('ads', $this->Advertisment->find('all'));
    }`

Comment: Did the answers work? Because we didn't here from you no more

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$belongsTo` in this case.

**Model :** `Advertisments.php`

```
class Advertisment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Adsite' => array(
            'className' => 'Adsite',
            'foreignKey' => 'adsite_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**Model :** `Adsites.php`

```
class Adsite extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = 'Advertisment';
}
```

**Controller** : `AdvertismentsController.php`

```
function index() { 
     $this->set('ads', $this->Advertisment->Adsite->find('all')); 
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, an `Advertisement` belongs to a `Site`, and a `Site` can have many `Advertisement` records. You’re also not naming your columns as per CakePHP’s conventions. If an `Advertisement` belongs to a `Site`, then your foreign key column should be named `site_id`.

Getting back to the question on hand, you could add the `Containable` behavior to your models, so that when you query one model, its related data is fetched too. So if you query an `Advertisement`, it would also fetch the corresponding `Site` record. Your models would look like this:

```
<?php
class Advertisement extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Advertisement';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('Site');
}
```

And your `Site` model:

```
<?php
class Site extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Site';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('Advertisement');
}
```

You can then query advertisements in the current site like this:

```
public function index() {
    $advertisements = $this->Advertisement->find('all');

    $this->set('advertisements', $advertisements);
}
```